# VB.net Asynchronous call to Url with no response needed

Tags: vb.net, http, asynchronous, https

I have a VB.Net page that needs to submit data to a url after a user clicks a button. I don't need any data back from the url, I just need to pass parameters to it and allow the user to continue to the next step without waiting for the url to do it's thing.

I've seen some similar posts for c# using UploadStringTaskAsync, but haven't been able to find a corresponding method for VB.net.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient.uploadstringtaskasync?view=net-6.0

I believe I can call the Async method from my existing nonasync methods as I don't need the response back. However, if there is a more elegant approach to do this please let me know.

Update with current code attempting to use thread:

```
Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
     If Not IsPostBack Then
          Dim thread As New Thread(AddressOf testSub)
          thread.Start()
     End If
End Sub

Sub testSub
     Using WC As New WebClient  WC.UploadString("https://someurl.com?parameter1=testing&parameter2=anothertest", "SOMEDATA")
     End Using
End Sub
```

This runs but unfortunately does not appear to handle any of the parameters. When I post the url directly in the browser it runs as expected. I don't need to send any data other than the querystring as well so I'm not sure if that's breaking the uploadstring. However, when I run it via debugger I don't see any errors so long as I populate that string for the data with a value.

I might be misunderstanding though when the await call is needed. While I don't need any data back, the external url can take up to 5 minutes to process. I'm wondering if it's taking too long and timing out after that thread is started.

Comment: Little bit of a tangent, you’re probably find it much more reliable to use HttpClient over WebClient

Comment: `UploadStringTaskAsync()` is a .Net method, it has nothing to do with the language. If it's about the documentation, in the MSDN Docs the language selector is in the upper-right band. -- It's quite preferable that you await that method. Since it's called from a Button click handler, no problem making the handler async.

Comment: You can always call an async function without using `Await`, if you don't care to wait for the result.  You'll get back a `Task` which you can ignore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could run it in its own thread.

```
Imports System.Net
Imports System.Threading

Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

        ' Create a thread to run this in the background
        Dim t As New Thread(
            Sub()
                Using WC As New WebClient
                    WC.UploadString("https://YOURURL", "YOURDATA")
                End Using

            End Sub
        )
        ' Start the thread
        t.Start()

    End Sub


End Class
```

Comment: Thank you for the replies.

I attempted the Thread implementation on pageload as a test, but the url does not appear to be hit.  Do I need to await that task in order for it to process? If I go to the url directly, it handles the querystring without issue.

Comment: How do you know the URL isn't being hit?

Comment: The url does an internal process with the provided parameters. When I run this code that process is not triggered. However, pasting the url directly into the browser runs the process.

Comment: Ah I see, taking out the threading portion I get an error that the "An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host". Ok I need to troubleshoot that first before I get back to this.

Comment: That did the trick, thank you Fawlty! The other error I was getting was due to not setting the security protocol to Tls12 before doing the call.

Comment: Brilliant :) - glad you got it sorted